# Filter Gmail Updates folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search, microsoft-office

Spent a couple of hours sorting out my mailbox in MS Outlook. Emptied the bin/deleted folder, cleared sent items etc.

Log onto gmail.com and noticed my storage is exactly the same. Checked all the folder/label structure and noticed its identical as my Outlook (Outlook 2016 and i know this is setup correctly with no errors and all sync activities are ok).

I eventually see a folder/label under **More > Updates** with 8000 emails, most of which are the ones i deleted from Outlook or moved them into relevant folders when i was organising email in Outlook.

1. How could i select all the emails which are not tagged with a folder/label (the tagged emails i want to keep, other are most likely to delete)? I looked at the search filter and nothing apparent there.
2. How could i stop emails arriving into the Updates folder, so once i organise them theres no reference here? I know how to turn this folder off or stop it from displaying but is this enough to stop this from happening in future?